# Set Page from Area Folder as default page in asp.net core 2.2 MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2

I want to set Login Page as Default page.Login page is present in Area Folder

Below is the project structure

[image]

i had tried to set default route in Startup.cs page but unable to set 
below is the snapshot of starup.cs

```
 app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
              name: "default",
              template: "identity/{controller=Account}/{action=Signin}");

        routes.MapRoute(
              name: "areaRoute",
              template: "{area:exists}/{controller}/{action}"
            );
    });
```

Every time i get error 404 error
not able to find where is the exact issue

Controller Code:

```
    [Area("Identity")]
    [Route("identity/[controller]")]
    public class AccountController : BaseController
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;


        public AccountController(
         UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
         SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager
         )
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
        }


        // GET: /Account/SignIn 
        [Route("[action]")]
        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SignIn(string returnUrl = null)
        {                
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to change your default page? It's possible to keep home as default page but redirect to Login if user isn't logged in. Personally I would prefer that aproach.

Comment: @chrillelundmark default page will be Login only we dont have any home page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I want to set Login Page as Default page.Login page is present in Area Folder*

The easiest way is to configure default values for `area`, `controller` and `action`:

```
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "identity/{controller=Account}/{action=Signin}");

        routes.MapRoute(
              name: "areaRoute",
              template: "{area:exists}/{controller}/{action}"
            );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "areaRoute",
            template: "{area=Identity}/{controller=Account}/{action=Signin}"
        );
    });
```

Controller code : Need to Remove Route parameter

```
    [Area("Identity")]        
    public class AccountController : BaseController
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;


        public AccountController(
         UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
         SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager
         )
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
        }


        // GET: /Account/SignIn            
        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SignIn(string returnUrl = null)
        {                
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tried the same but still it shows Status Code: 404; Not Found

Comment: @NileshGajare Did you enable other middlewares or routes ? I test my code, it works fine for me. Could you please show  us the complete code of startup.cs ?

Comment: @NileshGajare Also, did you decorate custom `[Route()]` or `HttpGet()` attributes on your `AccountController` or its actions ?

Comment: @NileshGajare this is not working for me either. Can you please guide if you find any solution on this?